# How to filter rows by one column?

Tags: awk, filter

Sorry if this is a basic question, I don't use linux often but I have a 13GB file that I want to filter down.

I have 123 columns and I want to remove rows that have only a `.` in the 75th column.

I've been looking into how to do this, at the moment I've got:

```
awk '$75 !~/./ {print $0}' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Am I along the right lines? When I run this it outputs an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
awk '$75 != "." ' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

this will match 75 th column for an extact dot.

what you did

```
awk '$75 !~/./ {print $0}'
```

will try to match 75th column for something different from any char (regexp match by `.` )

more precisely

```
awk '$75 ~ /./ '
```

will match any row where 75th columen have at least one char (which is all row, if you have more than 75 columns)